# Importing bookmarks into firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I currently have my own bookmarks application ([cakemarks](http://martin-ueding.de/en/projects/cakemarks/)) written in PHP running on my server. However, I am considering to just import all those bookmarks into Firefox.

The cakemarks project was started by me to have my bookmarks across all browsers and all devices. Since they live on a server, there is no need to sync, and I could use any browser I want. However, even on the impressive hexacore Opteron with 16 GB of RAM, this is painfully slow (it takes more than 500 ms to generate each page). Adding bookmarks cannot be done right in the browser, but has to be done through a bookmarklet and so on. By moving them back into my primary browser, I expect a big usability improvement, although I will use the ubiquity.

Now regarding the how: I know that Firefox supports to import and export bookmarks via HTML, but I am not sure whether I should just create an export which creates something like Firefox exports, or whether there is some better way.

Comment: Your question is unclear. We cannot understand what you are trying to ask/achieve yet.

Comment: Okay, I added a paragraph. Is it still unclear?

Comment: Thanks. As someone who has used Firefox for probably 10+ years now (including bookmarks export/import), my gut feeling is that the "best" way to do this would be to simply export to HTML, but I'm not a developer. What does cakemarks do that this can't? http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-sync-share-bookmarks-and-more-with-firefox-mobile

Comment: Cakemarks has let me use my bookmarks with any browser on any device in real time. Firefox Sync only works with Firefox browsers. However, I happen to use Firefox on my desktop all the time, and just marginally do casual browsing on the other devices. Therefore, I do not need that any more.

Answer (score 0):

Let your bookmarks application export its complete contents as .URL files (possibly in folder). Then simply drag and drop all of the .URL files to the open bookmarks TAB in Firefox. I don't know the application but I saw it exports in JSON so you can use php to [read the JSON](https://www.php.net/json_decode) file and traverse and generate the .URL files (which are just like [ini files](https://www.php.net/parse_ini_file))

Personally I keep all my bookmarks as .URL files and then generate webpages from the directories (e.g. this one: http://populair.eu/ : I sync my .URL files with Dropbox on the server and on the server I generate these pages).

(alternative is writing an application that traverses the bookmark sqlite db of firefox and enter all the urls)

Comment: I generated an `.url` file, but my Linux Firefox does not seem to be able to import it. Is that a Windows only feature?

Comment: on this moment... yes: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/119418 however this seems to work in linux (in the comments ) : http://steronius.blogspot.nl/2013/01/open-url-files-in-linux.html